# solving differential equation with matrices

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, differentials

I have to solve two coupled differential equations:

```
NDSolve[{D[u[1][t], t] - 2 t* v[1][t] == 0, 
      D[v[1][t], t] - 2 t* u[1][t] == 0, u[1][2] == {{1, 2}, {4, 5}}, 
      v[1][2] == {{3, 4}, {5, 4}}}, 
     Flatten[{Variables[u[1]], Variables[v[1]]}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

where,

```
u[1] = {{Subscript[\[Rho]1, ee], Subscript[\[Rho]1, ex]}, {SuperStar[
    Subscript[\[Rho]1, ex]], Subscript[\[Rho]1, xx]}} // MatrixForm
v[1] = {{Subscript[\[Rho]2, ee], Subscript[\[Rho]2, ex]}, {SuperStar[
    Subscript[\[Rho]2, ex]], Subscript[\[Rho]2, xx]}} // MatrixForm
```

The solution I am getting is the complete matrix but I want the individual elements as the solution.

```
 {{(Subscript[\[Rho]1, ee]  Subscript[\[Rho]1, ex]
    (Subscript[\[Rho]1, ex])^*  Subscript[\[Rho]1, xx]
    
    )->InterpolatingFunction[Domain: {{0.,10.}}
    Output dimensions: {2,2}
    
    ],(Subscript[\[Rho]2, ee]   Subscript[\[Rho]2, ex]
    (Subscript[\[Rho]2, ex])^*  Subscript[\[Rho]2, xx]
    
    )->InterpolatingFunction[Domain: {{0.,10.}}
    Output dimensions: {2,2}
   
    ]}}
```

Please suggest a way out.

Comment: Have you actually input this into your notebook while leaving `//MatrixForm` in your definitions for `u[1]` and `v[1]`?

Comment: yes. Is that the error?

Comment: I am not sure, but it is certainly *an* error. However, upon removing it, your code appears to be ill-defined, so you might want to investigate that. I am not sure why it would have ran at all to begin with.

Comment: Ok thanx. I removed that and tried to run the code but still there is some error.

Answer (score 2):

To get the matrix elements as single functions, you may try:

```
Clear[u, v]
u[1][t_] = Array[us[##][t] &, {2, 2}];
v[1][t_] = Array[vs[##][t] &, {2, 2}];
eq = Thread /@ 
   Flatten@(Thread /@ {D[u[1][t], t] - 2 t*v[1][t] == 
        ConstantArray[0, {2, 2}], 
       D[v[1][t], t] - 2 t*u[1][t] == ConstantArray[0, {2, 2}], 
       u[1][2] == {{1, 2}, {4, 5}}, v[1][2] == {{3, 4}, {5, 4}}});

sol = NDSolve[eq, Flatten[{u[1][t], v[1][t]}], {t, 0, 10}][[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: It worked. Thanx a lot.

Comment: How to define a matrix {{a11,a12,0},{a21,a22,0},{0,0,a33}} in this form of array?

Comment: Do you have a simple rule for the positions of the zeros? Otherwise: `mat= Array[a[##] &, {3, 3}]`or `mat=Array[Subscript[a,  ##] &, {3, 3}]`  or `mat=Array[Symbol["a" <> ToString[#1] <> ToString[#2]] &, {3, 3}]`  and then ,mat[[1,3]]=mat[[2,3]]=mat[[3,1]]=mat[[3,2]]

Comment: Are you saying mat[[1,3]]=mat[[2,3]]=mat[[3,1]]=mat[[3,2]]==0 ?

Comment: Yes, according to your specification: `{{a11,a12,0},{a21,a22,0},{0,0,a33}}`